# Is there any way to handle the omni channel Limits?

Tags: omnichannel

So I created a flow where a record will be assign to a queue depending on the status of the case priority (High, Medium, Low). This queue uses an omni channel. The problem is, omni channel has limits of 200000 records that can be put in the queue along with 45000 records per hour. If I reached this limit, the record will not be created. Is there any way to manage this kind of limitation?

Comment: Have you checked [Omni-channel Limit Exceeded Errors and Troubleshooting](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317857&type=1)

Comment: Also, these are hard limits and cannot be changed. Why do you need more than 200,000 work items in the queue at any time? Are the agents handling more than 45,000 work items per hour? Thanks

Comment: I just wanna make sure that there will be no problem record limit is reach.